# How to expand logical volume in HP ML150 gen 9 , smart hba h240

Tags: raid1

I have replaced two hotplug 300gb sas drives with 600gb sas drives (raid 1) . The smart storage administrator have no option of increasing the logical volume to the new drives. So now i'm stuck with 300gb-usable in a 600GB drive. How do I increase the logical volume to 600GB ? with out loosing data ? pls help   [screen shot of ssa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVN7f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to expand a logical drive array in SSA the storage controller needs to have a battery backed write cache according to the following HP [documentation](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=c03909334), page 76

> IMPORTANT: An array expansion, logical drive extension, or logical drive
> migration takes about 15 minutes per gigabyte. While this process is occurring, no
> other expansion, extension, or migration can occur simultaneously on the same
> controller. Controllers that do not support a battery-backed write cache do not
> support this process

To be able to utilize the extra space a new array and logical drive would need to be setup manually.
This could probably be achieved by removing one drive from the Raid and create a new raid and logical device then present it to the OS.
In the OS moving all the data to the new device and then remove the old array and logical device and then expanding the new array.

> Make sure to have a backup before trying to do anything like this, as the drive would be running without any redundancy and a drive failure would be catastrophic.